# IllegalStateException while using nested DialogFragments with Navigation Library

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment, android-jetpack-navigation

I am using Navigation library (2.2.0-rc04) and I have two DialogFragments. First one is A, opened from `MainFragment`. Second one is B and it is just an alert dialog for confirmation opened by A. Here is the the overall structure of the related navigation XML:

```xml
<navigation app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment" ...>

    <fragment android:id="@+id/mainFragment" ...>
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_ADialog"
            app:destination="@id/ADialog" />
    </fragment>

    <dialog
        android:id="@+id/ADialog"
        android:name="com...ADialog"
        android:label="ADialog"
        tools:layout="@layout/dialog_a">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_aDialog_to_bDialog"
            app:destination="@id/BDialog" />
    </dialog>

    <dialog
        android:id="@+id/BDialog"
        android:name="com...BDialog"
        android:label="BDialog" />

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_login"
        app:destination="@id/nav_graph_login"
        app:popUpTo="@id/mainFragment"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>

</navigation>
```

I want to have only one dialog appearing in the screen at a time. Therefore, when user taps a button on A to go to B, I call `dismiss()` on A right before I call `navigate(action_aDialog_to_bDialog)` to pop up B. B pops up but when I try to call `navigate(action_global_login)` from B, I get following error:

```
IllegalStateException: Fragment B not associated with a fragment manager.
```

Any ideas what the problem is and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than calling `dismiss()` programmatically, I updated the graph as follows:

```
<dialog
    android:id="@+id/ADialog"
    android:name="com...ADialog"
    android:label="ADialog"
    tools:layout="@layout/dialog_a">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_aDialog_to_bDialog"
        app:destination="@id/ADialog"
        app:popUpTo="@id/ADialog"
        app:destination="@id/BDialog" />
</dialog>
```